# How to insert cloned element with in HTML Markup String?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am in need of cloning a div and then append it it in another location. The DIV is looks like this.

```
<div id="clonableContet" class="clonableClass">
<input id="Name" class="clonableInput" type="text"/>
<input id="Age" class="clonableInput" type="text"/>
</div>

<div id="clonedContentHolder"></div>
```

If i clone `clonableContent` and append it in `clonaedContentHolder`, it contains the same ID
as the previous one. I want change the cloned Content `div's` id attribute dynamically. But i able to add new class name dynamically to the cloned `input` Elements. I am good with it. I will able to get the values with some class name reference.

But my problem is i want make last cloned content to be visible. Because, all of these `div's` are tab contents. I am not able to change the `clonableContent` div's id.

I tried to create a another div dynamically, and put the cloned div within that. Its like this,

```
var html = "<div id='clonedContent" + count + "'>" + clonedContent + "</div>";
```

But the output is [Object][Object]. cloned div, becames object within the String.

How shall i insert the clonedContent within a string as another string?

Or, is there any other way to get the same solution.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

create the html as such:

```
var html = $("<div />").attr('id', 'clonedContent'+count).html(clonedContent);
```

Then you can use html as a jquery object and append to as the last item as such:

```
html.appendTo('div:last');
```

Answer (score 1):

The best way I've found to do this is to `append` the object to an existing jQuery object:

```
var html = $("<div id='clonedContent" + count + "' />").append(clonedContent);
```

Answer (score 1):

Non JQuery solution:

```
var div = document.createElement("div"); //create a new div
div.id="clonedContent" + count; // set the id with your counter
div.appendChild(clonedContent); //add the DOM reference you have
document.getElementById("clonedContentHolder").appendChild( div ); //add the content to div on page
```